# Rota para página inicial Angular

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

Tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu módulo

https://jsfiddle.net/o0hs0uhw/

Quando eu chamo a URL http://localhost/emp/dist/boffice/home, ele inclui a view home.html, até ai tudo ok. O problema é que quando ele está nessa URL e eu dou um enter, me da uma mensagem de que a página não foi encontrada. Mesma coisa se eu digito a URL e coloco o /home no final, ele me apresenta o mesmo erro. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?
Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você habilitou `html5`, para que o sistema de rotas funcione corretamente com a utilização de `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` você deve definir também a raiz do seu app. Isso é feito dentro do seu head através da tag

```
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

Ou então, se o seu app possui uma pasta raiz diferente, defina ela ali, por exemplo:

```
<base href="/app/">
//ou
<base href="/app/adm/">
```

Outro ponto a ser observado (que eu já passei por esse problema) é que com esse método pode ser que os seus links quebrem, uma das soluções seria utilizar uma `/` antes da definição dos seus links, como `css`, `script`, etc.. Por exemplo, o seguinte `css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/main.min.css">
```

Ficaria assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/main.min.css"> //Note a barra invertida antes do dist
```

Lembrando também que para servidores diferentes, existem soluções diferentes, como por exemplo, no apache eu precisei habilitar o módulo `rewrite`, e assim por diante. Teste com essas soluções que lhe passei, se ainda assim não resolver, o seu problema pode ser relacionado ao servidor que está usando.

Comment: Valeu amigo, amanhã vou testar

Comment: Então, funcionou. MAs agora tem um porém, eu mudei a estrutura e agora a página inicial está so no / (antes era /home). Agora por exemplo se eu coloco /teste, me apresenta a página de erro. Pelo que eu vi no console, não está carregando o "teste.html", ele mostra so "teste". ISso se eu habilitar o html5. COm ele desabilitado fica normal

Comment: Isso deve estar associado com o modo que você monta suas rotas. Eu, por exemplo, utilizo ui-router e tenho definido um redirecionamento padrão. Quando o usuário acessar `site` ou `site/` (por exemplo) ele direciona automaticamente para `site/home`. Fora isso, também é necessário definir uma url para cada stete. Isso utilizando o ui-router, que pode ser diferente para você, caso utilize outro sistema de rota.