# Conflito de rotas no AngularJS e Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, route, routing

Estou tendo um problema com roteamento no AngularJS e Wordpress. Antes eu não usava o `html5Mode(true)` e minha rota era `/#/dashboad` e a rota `/blog` funcionava normalmente. Mas, quando eu comecei a usar `html5Mode(true)` e a rota passou a ser `/dashboard` o Angular começou a interpretar a rota `/blog` também e começou a dar erro 404 e eu não consigo mais acessar o blog. Não encontrei nenhuma solução para o AngularJS ignorar um padrão de rota sem usar o `target="_self"` no link.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Rota para página inicial Angular](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/121778/rota-para-p%c3%a1gina-inicial-angular)